# Concrete pour: consolidation vs too dry mix

Tags: concrete, repair, septic

Resealed the outlet baffle on a septic tank, and noticed a smallish crack under the outlet on the tank extending about 18in down, a little bit of the grey water was weeping out of the crack. I poured a fairly dry mix of concrete 3.5in thick to create a barrier buttress to seal the crack and reinforce the wall. After leaving the form in for a week, removed it and there's a fair amount of cratering toward the middle of the pour (see photos). I'm guessing not enough consolidation - I used a piece of rebar to disturb the mix several times as I went. This is 3 ft underground to the top of the poured edge, and it extends down another 20in, this is Maryland so freezing maybe not a concern. The goal is to keep the gray water in the tank and reinforce it. Still a rookie with concrete. Think we're good here? Is this going to be swiss cheese all the way through? Is the likelihood of spalling really a problem in this application (low pressure, low load)?
[image]

Comment: Any feedback? I think (I hope) that the cratering in the middle is superficial, looks pretty consolidated toward the top, this was a tall, narrow form so only the top side was exposed.